# Calculation of increased process efficiency

Tags: process-engineering, process-improvement

Say I have a process taking 19 h.
Some improvement measures allow to reduce the required time to 17 h (to reach the same level of output).

Does it make sense to say that the process is now (1-17/19)*100 ~= 10% more efficient?

If not, what kind of quantification of the process improvement would make sense?

Answer (score 1):

### Many Paths to Process Improvement

Processes can be improved in a variety of ways:

- Speed.
- Quality.
- Cost.
- Cycle time.
- Lead time.

and probably tons of other dimensions, too. If your process is *repeatably* two hours faster, rather than a statistical outlier, then you could certainly say your new-and-improved process is **10.5% faster** than before, but it may or may not be more **10.5% more efficient**.

### Speed <> Efficiency

Whether or not your process is actually more *efficient* depends on how you choose to interpret efficiency and what you want to get out of an optimized process. Consider these examples.

- If your process is 2 hours faster because you've added another person to the team, is that more efficient?
- If your process is 2 hours faster, but has an increased defect rate, is it more efficient?
- If your process is 2 hours faster but requires more fuel per widget produced, is it more efficient?

These aren't trick questions. The answer is just as likely to be *yes* as it is *no*, because for most organizations "efficiency" is a buzzword that's really a proxy for something else. In my own experience, it's most often a proxy for *value/time* or *value/cost*, but an engine manufacturer might think an improvement in the [rate of energy capture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_law_of_thermodynamics) is what the process ought to be optimized for.

Unlike some of the hard sciences, efficiency is a less objective term in project management. Therefore, your mileage will vary.

Comment: +1 for linking the 2. law. And I can see your point. I guess my understanding of "efficiency" is currently a bit cloudy.

Answer (score 0):

I would call that a 10% savings of time.  But time is only one factor of efficiency.  To look at the efficiency savings you need to capture the ratio of output/input of the before and output/input of the after and compare the delta.

Comment: And maybe also the ration of resource / workforce usage? It makes a lot of difference if the process takes 10% less time but 20% more raw materials / energy / employees to complete.

Answer (score 0):

In Lean, there is a [Process Cycle Efficiency](https://qualityamerica.com/LSS-Knowledge-Center/leansixsigma/process_cycle_efficiency.php) metric calculated as a ratio between cycle time and value-added time. From the 17h how much of it was valuable effort? For example: 5h (value-added time) / 17h (cycle time) = 30% (process efficiency).